# Correct Syntax on MySQL Table Joins?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have two tables that I'm trying to join into a new table. I have a "users" table, a "tasks" table and I have a blank "user_tasks" table. I'm trying to join them into the "user_tasks" table.

Here are my tables.

```
users = user_id, first_name, last_name
tasks = task_id, task_description
user_tasks = ut_id, ut_user_id, ut_first_name, ut_last_name, ut_task_id, ut_task_description.
```

Here is my PHP & SQL query. I'm not sure what is wrong. I get an undefined index. Do I need to add hidden inputs on my HTML form? Any help would be appreciated.

```
<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];

    $task_id = $_POST['task_id'];
    $task_description = $_POST['task_description'];

    $ut_id = $_POST['ut_id'];
    $ut_user_id = $_POST['ut_user_id'];
    $ut_first_name = $_POST['ut_first_name'];
    $ut_last_name = $_POST['ut_last_name'];
    $ut_task_id = $_POST['ut_task_id'];
    $ut_task_description = $_POST['ut_task_description'];

    $join_query = "SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name, tasks.task_id, tasks.task_description FROM users, tasks INNER JOIN user_tasks ON users.user_id = user_tasks.ut_id INNER JOIN user_tasks ON tasks.task_id = user_tasks.ut_id INSERT INTO user_tasks (ut_user_id, ut_first_name, ut_last_name, ut_task_id, ut_task_description) VALUES ($user_id, $first_name, '$last_name', '$task_id', $task_description) WHERE ('$first_name' = '$ut_first_name', '$last_name' = '$ut_last_name', $task_id = $ut_task_id, '$task_description' = '$ut_task_description') ";

    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $join_query);      

}
```

?>

Comment: What are you trying to do? Select or Insert? You are mixing both in the same query, and cant do that.

Comment: I'm trying to assign a task to a specific user. I have the form working just fine. But the data is not populating into the new table.

Comment: You have to provide more details on what you want. Show us sample data and expected result.

Comment: Ok I can do that. Sorry last time I posted something it was too long, so I tried to be brief on this one, but it is kind of a long question.

Answer (score 0):

I think the table('user,tasks') in your select is wrong,maybe the table is 'user_tasks'

Comment: Ok great. Thanks. I will check that a little closer and see if it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You have two concatenated queries,select + insert
, try this:
**1- insert + select separate:**

```
           $join_query = "SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name,
           users.last_name, tasks.task_id,
           tasks.task_description FROM users
           INNER JOIN user_tasks ON users.user_id = user_tasks.ut_user_id 
/*users.user_id = user_tasks.ut_id*/
           INNER JOIN tasks ON task.task_id=user_task.ut_task_id";

           $result = mysqli_query($connection, $join_query);
```

AND Insert After,Insert does not use where:

```
 $insert_query="INSERT INTO user_tasks (ut_user_id, ut_first_name,  ut_last_name,
                ut_task_id, ut_task_description) 
                VALUES ($user_id, '$first_name', '$last_name',
               '$task_id', '$task_description')";


mysqli_query($connection,$insert_query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

**2- INSERT with SELECT:**

```
$query="INSERT INTO user_tasks (ut_user_id, ut_first_name,  ut_last_name,
                    ut_task_id, ut_task_description) 
SELECT users.user_id, users.first_name,
           users.last_name, tasks.task_id,
           tasks.task_description FROM users
           INNER JOIN user_tasks ON users.user_id = user_tasks.ut_user_id   /*users.user_id = user_tasks.ut_id*/
           INNER JOIN tasks ON task.task_id=user_task.ut_task_id";

       mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_error($connection));
```

Comment: Ok great. So should I use both or one or the other?

Comment: It depends, the first  will insert only a record with the parameters of the POST , the second will insert the number of records returned by the select.

Comment: Ok thanks. I will try them both and see if they work. Thank you for your help.